# Pandas map, check if any values in a list is inside another

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

I have the following list

```
x  = [1,2,3]
```

And the following df

Sample df

```
pd.DataFrame({'UserId':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],'Origins':[1,2,3,2,2,3,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
```

Lets say I want to return, the userid who contains any of the values in the list, in his groupby origins list.

Wanted result

```
pd.Series({'UserId':[1,2]})
```

What would be the best approach? To do this, maybe a groupby with a lambda, but I am having a little trouble formulating the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['UserId'][df['Origins'].isin(x)].drop_duplicates()
```

I had considered using `unique()`, but that returns a numpy array. Since you wanted a series, I went with `drop_duplicates()`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, OP wants, for each `Origin`, the `UserId` whose number appears in list `x`. If that is the case, the following, using [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`pandas.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) will do the work

```
df_new = df[df['Origins'].isin(x)]['UserId'].unique()

[Out]:
[1 2]
```

Assuming one wants a series, one can convert the dataframe to a series as follows

```
df_new = pd.Series(df_new)

[Out]:
0    1
1    2
dtype: int64
```

If one wants to return a Series, and do it all in one step, instead of [`pandas.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.unique.html), one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) ([see Steven Rumbaliski answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73718343/7109869)).